# Climate Change Solutions - Pros and Cons

Tags: climate-change

I am beginning my research on climate change and am not familiar with all of the problems that can occur. At the same time, I know there are potential solutions to react to climate change.

For example, I know electric vehicles is a possible solution but at the same time there are downsides because it is expensive and other environmental negatives could result from this.

For example, fracking is an inexpensive way as an alternative to coal. At the same time though, it could cause air and water pollution along with risk of earthquakes.

Is there a list somewhere that has all of the potential solutions with pros and cons?

Comment: Check out [Project Drawdown](https://drawdown.org/): it's a ranking of climate change solutions by economic feasibility.

Comment: this is helpful, thanks

Comment: This is really helpful in terms of potential solutions. It doesn't show too many of the negative impacts. I am also looking for a pros and cons list to climate change solutions